# QString to double long float and long long int

Tags: c++, qt, floating-point, int, qstring

Is it possible to convert the part before the decimal point to long long int and the part after the decimal point to long double float?

Example:

QString "1101.110";

and I would like to change that into two variables:

long long = 1101

long double = 0.110

I tried:

```
QString input = ui->inputbox->text();

long long whole = input.toInt();

double long fraction = input.toFloat();
```

If I input a number 110.10011:

whole outputs 0

fraction outputs 110.1 but I want it to output 0.10011

Comment: The trivial solution is to subtract `whole` from fraction. Alternatively, a more straightforward approach is to just use `toFloat` and call `modf` on the result.

Comment: toInt() is probably failing to convert since it is a floating point number. If you used the parameter (pointer to bool) I expect the bool to be set to false. http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#toInt

Comment: What about splitting the string first ?

Comment: @MatteoItalia how I convert double &intpart to int then?

Comment: `double val = input.toDouble();` will convert to double.  `double intPart,fraction;` and  `fraction = std::modf(val,&intPart);`

Comment: See the example here for modf usage: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/modf

Comment: @Xatyrian how would I split the string?

Comment: `QString::split`

Comment: A C solution: `long long ll = strtoll(input, &endptr, 0); double frac = strtod(endptr, &endptr);`